# Vue js: Accessing prod.env.js or data variable of a component in the dist folder

Tags: vue.js, variables, deployment, config

How can i access variables of a component or a global variable inside the prod.env.js inside the dist folder.

example:

inside my prod.env.js

```
'use strict'
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"',
  ROOT_API: '"http://10.250.252.1:43001"'
}
```

inside a component

```
adres: process.env.ROOT_API
```

how can i access variable adres or ROOT_API from my dist folder.

i want to create a config file inside my dist folder, so i can just send them the dist folder and they can replace their ROOT_API and not the full project.

is this possible and how can I do that. didn't find much about it on google.